Email from Jenkins with execution details of karate framework
I need to publish pass and fail count of execution from karate , where execution details are html report on email from Jenkins
I have html report which has the pass and failed details, these when I'm trying to add on pipeline under post block under email section in table format . I'm not getting the pass/fail detailsjenli

are you successfully emailing the report but the report that comes into the inbox does not have the test details? otherwise not sure what your issue is describing.
